# Where do i find DbDataController for my MVC4 application

Tags: controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I just saw http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159

but I cant find any of the stuff about Single Page Application. I saw a note that its not released with MVC4.

I have a MVC 4 Application, and using Controller and ApiController right now. I would like to try out this DbDataController - its located in System.Web.Http.Data.EntityFramework dll from what i found.

Now how do i find/add this to my project? Are there a nuget packaged for it?

I found this: http://nuget.org/packages/SinglePageApplication  but it also included alot of other stuff.